Flute in Rust error[E0432]: unresolved import `std::os::fd` could not find `fd` in `os`
I clone https://github.com/ypo/flute
And follow the guide I can do basic receive and send.
I notice there are example receiver/sender projects that seems able to transplant directly.
But when I cd to the example project and cargo build I got tons of errors and the first of them is

error[E0432]: unresolved import std::os::fd. could not find fd in
os.

I check standard lib, it does have fd in os
https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.78.0/std/os/fd/index.html.
I'm very new to rust that I'm not sure if I missed something obvious?

For what platform are you building code? Module std::os::fd is only supported for unix and wasi platforms.

I'm using Windows, this there a way I can workaround this?
